# Flutter BloC with multiple datasource streams

Tags: flutter, bloc, clean-architecture, flutter-bloc

In a Flutter project following the **Clean Architecture**, I wonder how can I use the **BLoC pattern** to handle a `UseCase` that returns two (or possibly more) `Stream`s for my screen.

Basically, my screen is supposed to display two different types of data that are retrieved via two different API calls. These data are wrapped in streams because they can change at any time and independently since I am using Firebase Real-time Database.

Following the Clean Architecture, I have:

- a `RemoteDataSource` that returns these streams.
- a `Repository` belonging to my `Feature` that returns these streams but also maps the data models to entity models with mappers.
- finally, I have my `UseCase` that communicates with said `Repository` to return the two streams.

Up to this point, I am satisfied with my clean architecture implementation.

Then I started to implement **the presentation layer** with the BLoC pattern. This is where I faced my issue. As the documentation says, BLoC expects a stream of `Event`s and emits in return a stream of `State`s. Such states are unique, and immutable and describe a reality of things.

So the way the `BlocBuilder` works, is that it tells me which `State` is active/current, and in return, I build my screen accordingly.

**=> Because of that, It is my understanding that I have no other choice than create one BLoC per data type**

I don't see a different way.

Comment: what do you mean with your last sentence: create one BLoC per data type, do you mean a state or an entire bloc ? @Mackovich